# Gulp task: Streams inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

The point is to read all files inside `someFolder` and then injecting them in a fixed file with `gulp-inject-string` *using an irrelevant criteria for this question*.

Some pseudo code of what I have:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject-string');
var fs = require("fs");

gulp.task('compile', function() {
  
 /* reading the file names in the directory */
 var fileNames = fs.readdirSync('someFolder', 'utf8');
 fileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
      
  /* getting the whole file content and then removing what 
  I don't want to be injected with a regex */
  var wholeFile = fs.readFileSync('someFolder/' + fileName, 'utf8');
  var file = wholeFile.replace(/<!-- COMMENT-WITH-SOME-FIXED-STRING:. * -->[\r\n]/g, '');
      
  /* now getting into mainFile to inject this file */
  gulp.src('mainFolder/mainFile.html')
        
  /* injecting the content after it has been processed by the regex exactly where I need it
  (which depends on the fileName I got earlier) */
  .pipe(inject.afterEach('<!-- COMMENT-WITH-SOME-FIXED-STRING+FILENAME: ' + fileName + ' -->', file))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('mainFolder'));
      
 });
});
```

This works correctly if I only have 1 file inside `someFolder`, otherwise it only injects the last read file.

I've tried to soak up the stream into an anonymous function inside a common for loop doing something like:

`for(var i...){ (function(i){ /* stream stuff here*/ })(i) }` as I've done several times with asynchronous operations in javascript but had the exact same result.

I also tried use `merge-stream` mapping a function over `fileNames` that returns the streams themselves and then applying the merge, but again, same result.

What am I doing wrong while attempting to handle the streams?

Comment: Are you just trying to concat a bunch of files together? Why not use [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat)?

Comment: @StevenLambert no, I'm injecting the files into the principal one using `inject` with an irrelevant to the main problem criteria after performing a regex and some cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject-string');
var fs = require("fs");

gulp.task('compile', function() {
    /* reading the file names in the directory */
    var fileNames = fs.readdirSync('someFolder', 'utf8');
    var stream = gulp.src('mainFolder/mainFile.html');
    fileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
        var file = fs.readFileSync('someFolder/' + fileName, 'utf8');

        stream = stream.pipe(inject.afterEach('<!-- include: ' +
                                              fileName + ' -->', file));

    });
    return stream.pipe(gulp.dest('destFolder'));
});
```

I've not done the text replacement on `mainFolder/mainFile.html` because it is not what was causing your failures and it is trivial to add. I'm also sending the output to a different folder (`destFolder`) because I absolutely hate gulpfiles that modify their input in place. It makes debugging such gulpfiles very difficult.

The keys are:

1. You need to return something to Gulp so that it knows when your task is over. Otherwise, it *may* terminate before the task is over.
2. You have to return the result of chaining all the actions on your stream.
3. It is generally possible to have multiple `gulp.dest` in a single stream but in this case you should have only one `gulp.dest` used, otherwise, you'll get only partial results.

Given the following inputs.

```
$ cat mainFolder/mainFile.html 
<!-- include: a -->
Other stuff.
<!-- include: b -->
Other stuff.
<!-- include: a -->
Other stuff.
<!-- include: b -->

$ cat someFolder/a 
File a's contents.

$ cat someFolder/b 
File b's contents.
```

Running `gulp compile` produces:

```
$ cat destFolder/mainFile.html 
<!-- include: a -->File a's contents.

Other stuff.
<!-- include: b -->File b's contents.

Other stuff.
<!-- include: a -->File a's contents.

Other stuff.
<!-- include: b -->File b's contents.
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. What is the point of the return statement in Gulp? With these particular examples I'm getting the same behavior and console logs with and without the return.

Comment: The return is necessary to *ensure* that Gulp knows when your asynchronous task is done. (And you task here, *is* asynchronous because `gulp.src` is asynchronous.) If you do not put it, it *may* work but that's luck. If the task is very fast, for instance, it may get to run completely before Gulp finishes its book keeping. For tasks that are synchronous, the return is not necessary (or desirable, even). I have an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33419479/1906307) about the ways to tell gulp when the task is done.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `fs` to directory and files you can just have `gulp.src` do it for you and then inject each file into the primary file.

```
gulp.src('someFolder/*.*')  // or a specific file type
  .pipe(inject.afterEach('someCriteriaInTheMainFile', file))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('mainFileFolderContainer'));
```

Comment: This was my first aproach, but I needed to get the piped file name and then perform a regex to replace some unnecessary strings in it based on the file name and THEN inject it. I'll edit the original question to be a little more descriptive with almost the exact code I have.